# How to get the NDVI value and the coordinates of each pixel within a geometry?

Tags: google-earth-engine, extract-by-mask

I would like to know how to extract the NDVI values from a list of points and export them in a file in CSV format with the following structure: LAT / LONG / NDVI.

I managed to get to a certain point in the code and I couldn't move forward.

```
var collection = sent2
.filterDate('2015-06-30', '2016-06-30')
.filterBounds(geometry)
.sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
.select('B2','B3','B4','B8');

// Image list
var imagesList = collection.toList(collection.size());

// Best image
var image = ee.Image(imagesList.get(6));

// NDVI
var red = image.select('B4');
var nir = image.select('B8');

var ndvi = image.expression('(nir - red) / (nir + red)', {
  nir: nir,
  red: red
}).select(['B8'],['ndvi']);

// Getting the projection of images
var proj = image.projection();

// Lat Long image
var latLong = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().reproject(proj);

// Getting a list of lat and long coordinates
var coords = latLong.select(['longitude', 'latitude'])
                      .reduceRegion({
                        reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
                        geometry: geometry,
                        scale: 10
                      });

// Putting lat and long information in separate lists
var lat = ee.List(coords.get('latitude'));
var long = ee.List(coords.get('longitude'));

// Creating a list of coordinates and converting them into points
var points = long.zip(lat).map(function (latLongList) {
  return ee.Geometry.Point(latLongList);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to post the code directly in your question, as it makes it easier to understand what you have done, and also makes your question searchable in the future.

There are a lot of parts of your code that are not necessary (reproject, etc.) but you will start understanding which are crucial or not as you become more familiar with how Earth Engine works.

If you add this code snippet at the end of your code, it should work.

```
var myData = ee.List(ndvi.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.toList(),geometry,10).get("ndvi")) //get NDVI

var allData = long.zip(lat).zip(myData); // add coords and NDVI as list

var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(allData.map(function(element){
  element = ee.List(element)  // tell it that it is a list
  var feature = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(element.get(0)),{NDVI:element.get(1)})  // create the feature
  return feature
}))

Export.table.toDrive(myFeatures);  //export is as a csv.
```

When you run it, you will have to assign a folder to export it, and give it a name.  Good Luck!

Comment: The result came very close to what I was looking for and with some modifications I got the following structure:

coords: [long, lat]
ndvi: ndvi value

What I'm still not getting is to separate the [long, lat] structure into:
long: long value
lat: lat value
ndvi: ndvi value

Comment: I got the answer on this link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/364407/168758
Thanks for your attention.